# Accessing mqtt broker via node.js and socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, mqtt

I am new to both MQTT and node.js, so please excuse me if I don't get all the terms correct, nor understand how all the pieces fit together

I am trying to follow the example: http://blog.hekkers.net/2012/10/13/realtime-data-with-mqtt-node-js-mqtt-js-and-socket-io/

I can't seem to get it right, the html page never displays the value/payload of the topic.

As I understand it, there are two files the node.js file and the html file. For the node.js file I have installed the required modules: socket.io and MQTTClient.js. My node.js file - pusher.js:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var net = require('net');
var mqtt = require('./node_mqtt_client/MQTTClient.js');

var io  = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var client = new mqtt.MQTTClient(1883, '192.168.1.108', 'pusher');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
    console.log('Subscribing to '+data.topic);
    client.subscribe(data.topic);
  });
});

client.addListener('mqttData', function(topic, payload){
  sys.puts(topic+'='+payload);
  io.sockets.emit('mqtt',{'topic':String(topic),'payload':String(payload)});
});
```

The 108 IP is the IP of the RabbitMQ Broker.

It seems to load fine, when I access the html file the console prints the following   information:

```
info  - socket.io started
Connected as :pusher
Session opend
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized FAxJSO4DUEXV5wi50E-k
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/FAxJSO4DUEXV5wi50E-k
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client FAxJSO4DUEXV5wi50E-k
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
Subscribing to aujen/weather/current/pressure
Subcribe to:aujen/weather/current/pressure
Connection closed by broker
   info  - transport end (undefined)
   debug - set close timeout for client FAxJSO4DUEXV5wi50E-k
   debug - cleared close timeout for client FAxJSO4DUEXV5wi50E-k
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client FAxJSO4DUEXV5wi50E-k
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized AqzQ60WhMDA1_Ddv0E-l
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/AqzQ60WhMDA1_Ddv0E-l
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client AqzQ60WhMDA1_Ddv0E-l
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
Subscribing to aujen/weather/current/pressure
MQTT connect to server time out
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client AqzQ60WhMDA1_Ddv0E-l
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client AqzQ60WhMDA1_Ddv0E-l
   debug - got heartbeat packet
```

For the html part, I have install apache to host the page - plain apache no extra modules. I have also download the required library files and placed them in the same folder as my html file: socket.io.min.js and jquery-1.4.2.js. My html files is as follows: index.html

```
<h1>Real Time</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.106:5000');
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      socket.on('mqtt', function (msg) {
        var elmarr=msg.topic.split("/");
        var elm=elmarr[3];
        console.log(msg.topic+' '+msg.payload);
        $('#'.concat(elm)).html(msg.payload);
     });
     socket.emit('subscribe',{topic:'aujen/weather/current/pressure'});
    });
</script>
<table class="tablegv" style="width: 500px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="tablegvHeader">
<td colspan="2"><center>Status</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Return temp</td>
<td id="pressure"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The 106 IP is the IP of my node.js server.

**The html page does not display the value/payload? of the topic, nor does the pusher.js(Not sure if it is supposed to)**

I know my broker(RabbitMQ) is working as I have also practiced creating a python script that subscribes the topics and it displays the values/payloads?.

```
python mqtt_sub.py 
rc: 0
Subscribed: 1 (0,)
aujen/weather/current/pressure 0 856.64
aujen/weather/current/temperature 0 25.63
aujen/weather/current/humidity 0 37

aujen/weather/current/pressure 0 856.67
aujen/weather/current/temperature 0 25.63
aujen/weather/current/humidity 0 36

aujen/weather/current/pressure 0 856.59
aujen/weather/current/temperature 0 25.62
aujen/weather/current/humidity 0 37
```

I can't seem to find to many examples of trying to use this method to integrate with the broker, most examples call the mosquitto_sub client from the js file - Not too keen on this.

Hopefully someone out there can point out what I have done wrong.
Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error when I was using RabbitMQ + MQTT plugin.
After I changed MQTT broker to mosquitto, it was ok.

I tried to change MQTT client to mqtt plugin of node.js (npm install mqtt), instead of node_mqtt_client/MQTTClient.js.
When I was using this, I could use RabbitMQ + MQTT plugin without error.
But I need to change pusher.js a little in this case.

```
var sys = require('sys');
var net = require('net');
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var io  = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var client = mqtt.createClient(1883, '127.0.0.1');

client.options.reconnectPeriod = 0;

client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  console.log(message);
  sys.puts(topic+'='+message);
  io.sockets.in(topic).emit('mqtt',{'topic': String(topic), 'payload':String(message)});
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
    console.log('Subscribing to '+data.topic);
    socket.join(data.topic);
    client.subscribe(data.topic);
  });
});
```